# how to get last inserted row id in sqlite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, titanium, appcelerator, rowid

```
function insertToProject(cast, pName)
{
    db.execute('INSERT INTO project (cd, pn) VALUES (?,?)', cast, pName);
        var x = last_insert_rowid();
        return x;
}
```

I have been trying this using javascript in titanium appcelerator. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: no errors? some more information would be usefun

Comment: thanks but I got it.. have to use -  var x = db.lastInsertRowId; instead of last_insert_rowid();

Comment: I know, I'm just asking if there is any errors? What is the `x` value when you run your code?

Comment: line = 19;
message = "Can't find variable: last_insert_rowid"; Earlier I was getting this error. Now I am getting the x as the last id being inserted.

Answer (score 5):

For this you can use the `lastInsertRowId` property of **database object**.

You can use like:

```
var x = db.lastInsertRowId;
```

#### lastInsertRowId

> `lastInsertRowId` : Number
>
> The identifier of the last populated row

Please check this link for more details : [Titanium.Database.DB](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Database.DB)

Answer (score 2):

You may also do:

```
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO project (cd, pn) VALUES (?,?)", cast, 
                function(tx, res) {
                    var id = res.insertId;
                });
      });
```

Thus, getting the result of the successful insert and then its property **insertId**